# In R, how to combine two data frames where column names in one equals row values in another?

Tags: r

Say I have one data frame of tooth brush brands and a measure of how popular they are over time:

```
year  brand_1  brand_2
2010  0.7      0.3
2011  0.6      0.6
2012  0.4      0.9
```

And another that says when each tooth brush brand went electrical, with `NA` meaning they never did so:

```
brand    went_electrical_year
brand_1  NA
brand_2  2011
```

Now I'd like to combine these to get the prevalence of electrical tooth brush brands (as a proportion of the total) each year:

```
year  electrical_prevalence
2010  0
2011  0.5
2012  0.69
```

In 2010 it's 0 b/c none of the brands are electrical. In 2011 it's 0.5 b/c both are and they are equally prevalent. In 2012 it's 0.69 b/c both are but the electrical one is more prevalent.

I've wrestled with this in R but can't figure out a way to do it. Would appreciate any help or suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: Can you add the `year` they went electric to the first data frame? Can you write a formula for how to calculate `electrical_prevalence`?  After that, can you compute from the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data frames are `df1` and `df2`, you can use the following `tidyverse` approach.

First, use `pivot_longer` to put your data into a long format which will be easier to manipulate. Use `left_join` to add the relevant years of when the brands went electrical.

We can create an indicator `mult` which will be 1 if the brand has gone electrical, or zero if it hadn't.

Then, for each year, you can determine the proportion by multiplying the popularity value by `mult` for each brand, and then dividing by the total sum for that year.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -year) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("name" = "brand")) %>%
  mutate(mult = ifelse(went_electrical_year > year | is.na(went_electrical_year), 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(electrical_prevalence = sum(value * mult) / sum(value))
```

**Output**

```
   year electrical_prevalence
  <int>                 <dbl>
1  2010                 0    
2  2011                 0.5  
3  2012                 0.692
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that was both very instructive & it solved my problem perfectly!